# Python - To match a list of string words present in a existing text file

Tags: python, selenium

Need to match a set of words in a text file.
The set of words are present separately in different lines.
A number of occurrences do not matter, but there must be at least 1 occurrence.
Only if all the words match exactly it's a PASS, else test is a FAIL.

I have created a file with contents :

```
file1 = open("MyFile.txt","a+")
```

Now, the list is

```
list = ["SIMPLE", "QUICK", "ADVANCED"]
```

Below code works for a single string but does not work with a list.

```
    with open("C:/Users/vikp/Desktop/MyFile.txt") as file1:
        for line in file1:
            if list in line:
                <assert pass condition> 
            else:
                <assert fail condition>
```

Comment: You should call `.strip()` before compare with your sample!

Comment: Do you allow any words other than "simple", "quick", and "advanced" in your file?

Comment: What do the contents of `MyFile.txt` look like?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one word on each line, right? If that's the case, you can test the validity of the line by `line in mylist`. The code assumes you don't allow any words other than those in `mylist`.

```
occurred = set()  # this set tests for at least one occurrence of each word
with open("C:/Users/vikp/Desktop/MyFile.txt") as file1:
    for word in file1:
        word = word.strip()  # get rid of new-line or whitespace characters
        if word in mylist:  # assume one word per line
            occurred.add(word)
        else:
            raise ValueError(word + ' is not in mylist')
# success if the for loop finishes without error AND all words occurred at least once
if len(occurred) == len(mylist):
    print('success')
else:
    missing = set(mylist) - occurred
    raise ValueError('the following words are missing: '+str(missing))
```

Comment: Just updated my answer to account for "at least one occurrence".

Answer (score 0):

Use set instead of list there and you can try this solution with regex :

```
import re
list = {"SIMPLE", "QUICK", "ADVANCED"}

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=set()
        for item in list:
            if re.findall(item,line):
                match.add("".join(re.findall(item,line)))


        if list-match==set():
            print(" Test pass")
            #<assert pass condition>
        else:
            print("Test fail")
            #<assert fail condition>
```

I have test with file.txt which contain:

```
SIMPLE and QUICK are winners they are ADVANCED too.
SIMPLE and QUICK are winners they are ADVANCED too.
SIMPLE and QUICK are winners they are ADVANCED too wowow.
```

output:

```
 Test pass
 Test pass
 Test pass
```

If your words are not as I tried with the dummy file, still regex will match perfectly.